# Defining feedback networks and its type

Tags: transistors, mosfet, current, amplifier, feedback

I am trying to do some exercises that focus on finding the closed loop gain of the following schematic.[image: schematic 1]

Here I can recognize a shunt-series topology due to the current I_out being sampled at RM, being converted to a voltage and through M1 it goes back to a current that is going to be compared with I_in. My main question is what is exactly the feedback network, is M1 as a whole included? What about R1, do we consider it as a sampling circuit for the input?.

Also for this other circuit Im not so sure about M6, it does create a current as an error signal and its then mixed at its drain, or we can say it works as a common source stage for the error signal making it a voltage mixer (?). This raises the question as to where do you check if the signal is parallel or series, does is this at the "comparating" node?

[image: schematic 2]

Any help is appreciated!